# How to make Unity Dash Background darker?

Tags: unity, 11.10, unity-dash

How do you make the unity dash background darker like in natty? Blur effect is too laggy and without the blur, it becomes confusing.

Comment: You cannot, which has been reported as bug (I'm not totally sure that's the right one, but here you go: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/851331). As we here at Ask Ubuntu cannot help with such issues, I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @htorque Actually, in a way, you can, like doug indicated below by taking advantage of the Dash's color-changing based on your wallpaper. Just pick a darker background and you're set. Of course, this won't do you any good if you also want to have a lighter background, in which case a new bug should be filed (the one you posted doesn't look relevant to me, as it discusses transparency rather than darkness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the static blur option, it's set the first time you use the dash in a session for the life of the session, may be less of a performance issue.

If you wish it to look a bit like the no blur used to be, (for all of a couple of wk's) then open the dash over a full screen dark solid color like dark blue or black

Edit: A small workaround till no blur becomes useful & if your current background  isn't what you'd like

create a solid color .html - this is for black, a very dark blue works well

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Dash Background</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#000000;">
</body>
</html>.
```

Then at session start open the .html in firefox & go

F11

tap the Super button to open dash, tap again to close

F11

Comment: Should have mentioned that this option is in `ccsm`.

Comment: I want something simpler... I dont want to do this on every start up.